# Checking for record across has_many relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I have the following models:

```
Event
has_many :user through :event_users
has_many :event_users

User
has_many :events, through: :event_users
has_many :event_users
has_many :event_user_groups

EventUser
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event_user_group, foreign_key: "group_id"
has_many :choices

EventUserGroup
belongs_to :event
has_many :users, through: :event_users
has_many :event_users, foreign_key: :group_id

Choices
belongs_to :event_user
```

Basically, users vote for a particular user in each group within an event. The event page has a form for each group, they pick the user which becomes their "choice" for that group.

```
<% @event.event_user_groups.each do |group| %>
    <%= form_for @event, :url => { :controller => "events", :action => :create_choice }, validate: true do |f| %>
      <h4> <%= group.try(:name) %> </h4>
      <% @event.event_users.where(:group_id => group.id).each do |user| %>
         <%= radio_button("groups", "user", user.id) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is all working perfectly, however currently users are able to vote multiple times because the form is rendered for every group when they load the page regardless if they have already created a choice for an event_user in that group, so what I'm trying to do is to construct an if statement inside the first each loop, to determine if the form should be displayed...

***"If the logged in user has already created a choice record for any of the event_users in this event_user_group, don't display the form."***

Comment: _"currently users are able to vote multiple times because the form is rendered"_ - well, get started by adding a validation on models, so that multiple voting is not possible in any way.